# GSON has an EOF error when loading from a resource

Tags: java, android, xml, json, gson

I am trying to use GSON to convert a Json string to an object.  When I load the string from a file like this:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "jsonTest");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String Json = br.readLine();
    br.close();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    dreFieldArray = gson.fromJson(Json, DreField[].class);
```

It works fine.  However, if I try to use a string resource instead like this:

```
String Json = this.getString(R.string.NewFileData);
Gson gson = new Gson();
    dreFieldArray = gson.fromJson(Json, DreField[].class);
```

I get an EOFexception.  The string in resources was copied from the file, so it should be identical.  I read that this exception can occur if there are extra characters after the object, but I don't see any.  Any ideas on what is going wrong here?

Comment: Post the actual stack trace? Or use the debugger and see what the actual difference is between the two `String`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getString()` will not display all special characters. You might have to escape them.

Log the content of `R.string.NewFileData`, see the missing characters and then escape them in the `strings.xml` (put a "\" in front of the removed characters)

Comment: Yes, I needed to escape using \

Answer (score 0):

how about try use

```
String Json= "{\"userName\":\"hello\",\"userId\":123}"
```

instead of `String Json = this.getString(R.string.NewFileData);`

cause the readline analysis paragraph by `\r\n`

if you put message `e.printStackTrace()` of `IOException`will be more helpful